# How to make main.bat go to :start when i open second.bat?

Tags: batch-file

So, I want to make main.bat go to menu :start when i open second.bat.

For example, my main.bat looks like this:

```
@echo off  
goto :1  
:start  
echo Hello  
pause  
exit  
:1  
echo Hi  
pause  
exit
```

And in my second.bat i want to have some sort of code that will make the main.bat go to :start. Batch pseudo-code would be like this:

```
@echo off  
in main.bat goto :start  
exit
```

Comment: You would need to pass an argument to main.bat and then you would need to change main.bat to check if any arguments were passed to it at the top of the script.

Comment: And how do i do that? @Squashman

Comment: You should do quite a bit more research on your own; [SO] is not a script-writing service. You should start by looking for some batch tutorials - Google can help here - and bookmark a good reference site - [SS64 on CMD.EXE](https://ss64.com/nt/) is the one I use.

Comment: Ok i figured it out. But i have one more question. Is it possible to do the same thing but without hardcoding stuff into main.bat?

Comment: If the flow of a script isn't expecting to be manipulated, it can't be manipulated.

Comment: @SomethingDark Not quite right, the feature/bug in my answer exists IIRC since Windows NT.

Comment: When your question is answeres, don't add [SOLVED] to the question title, but [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a call :start inside second.bat and then running main.bat without call.

This way program flow swaps to start in main.bat which would otherwise be inaccessible.

main.bat

```
@echo off
goto :1
:start
echo Hello from start in main.bat
pause
exit /b
:1
echo Hi
pause
exit /b
```

second.bat

```
@echo off
call :start
exit /b
:start
main.bat
```

> C:\Test> second.bat
>   Hello from start in main.bat
>   Press any key . . .

Comment: What does the /b after exit do? I dont understand the articles on that on the internet. EDIT: Your script works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you test the batch out of a cmd window exit will close the window while exit /b only exits the batch.

Comment: Hey LotPings? I cannot ask another question for now, so i will ask you. I have a problem because when i set a variable to file's content `set/p content=<file.txt` then i cannot compare it to a user input by if command. I cannot do that:
`set/p choice="> "  
set/p content=<file.txt  
if %choice%==%content% (...)`